# Difference between 2 Erlang Random Variables with the same parameter rate

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have 2 Erlang random variables, X and Y, that are independent.
Let Z = Y - X and assume that the rate parameter for both X and Y is 1. 
X ~ Erlang(1, 1) and Y ~ Erlang(3,1).

From my intuition, I think that Z ~ Erlang(2, 1). This means that the moment generating function of Z is ($\frac{1}{1-t}$)$^2$

However, when I try to derive this I get stuck. This is what I have

E[$e^{-tZ}$] = E[$e^{-t(Y - X)}$] = E[$e^{-tY}$]*E[$e^{+tX}$] = ($\frac{1}{1-t}$)$^3$ * ($\frac{1}{1+t}$)

This is not equivalent not ($\frac{1}{1-t}$)$^2$ which means that either my intuition is wrong or I did something wrong in the derivation.
Could someone kindly point out to me what I did wrong with an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is wrong.

Notice that $Z=Y-X$ is a random variable here with: $$P(Z<0)=P(X>Y)>0$$so cannot have Erlang-distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just got confused when thinking about the following.

Suppose we have X1 + X2  (independent) and ~ exp(1) each 
(also Erlang(1, 1) of course)
Their sum, say Y, ~ Erlang(2, 1)). If we apply the intuition, then:
X2 = (Y - X1) ~ Erlang(2 - 1, 1) = Erlang(1, 1) = exp(1) as given.
Why does my intuition hold here then or is it the case that X2 now has been redefined with this algebraic manipulation?

Comment: In the case you sketch in your comment $X_1$ and $Y$ are **not** independent. In that sense it differs from the case sketched in your question.